# webpack: comma in string causes syntax error during bundle

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, bundle, es6-modules

i am trying to bundle this file into my main js.

```
var constants = {
    height: 600,
    width: 400,
    default_bezier = "[ { \"startPoint\" : [51.6503017608354,203.464445873753], \"endPoint\" : [-52.41285540263849,202.37245643258615], \"startControlPoint\": [-9.043960791649624,202.53176818590896], \"endControlPoint\" : [-57.822702172883595,218.9418611624324] }, { \"startPoint\" : [-52.41285540263849,202.37245643258615], \"endPoint\" : [-5.570997193470086,172.0221729966046], \"startControlPoint\": [-47.00300863239339,185.8030517027399], \"endControlPoint\" : [-23.03585320491517,179.86237947171952] }, { \"startPoint\" : [-5.570997193470086,172.0221729966046], \"endPoint\" : [9.324396434959688,9.376975066207507], \"startControlPoint\": [10.884005326634842,164.63530320382674], \"endControlPoint\" : [-4.968072864533834,110.62618662928577] }, { \"startPoint\" : [9.324396434959688,9.376975066207507], \"endPoint\" : [5.6297169670964,-110.17611809084356], \"startControlPoint\": [23.153152351097606,-88.58724679549941], \"endControlPoint\" : [-7.361202275296376,-53.760928830398264] }, { \"startPoint\" : [5.6297169670964,-110.17611809084356], \"endPoint\" : [53.717335525525975,-176.2424857013046], \"startControlPoint\": [14.357981611994795,-148.08003333114038], \"endControlPoint\" : [28.00328937556781,-176.2424857013046] } ]"
}

export {constants};
```

however it gives this syntax error unexpected token, and then points at the comma:

```
ERROR in ./app/public/wp-content/themes/rise-child/js/maker-two/constants.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:\Users\tinti\Local Sites\sextoys\app\public\wp-content\themes\rise-child\js\maker-two\constants.js:
expected token (5:16)

  3 |   height: 600,
  4 |   width: 400,
> 5 |   default_bezier = "[ { 'startPoint' : [51.6503017608354,203.464445873753], 'endPoint' : [-52.41285540263849,202.37245643258615], 'star
ntrolPoint': [-9.043960791649624,202.53176818590896], 'endControlPoint' : [-57.822702172883595,218.9418611624324] }, { 'startPoint' : [-52.41
540263849,202.37245643258615], 'endPoint' : [-5.570997193470086,172.0221729966046], 'startControlPoint': [-47.00300863239339,185.803051702739
 'endControlPoint' : [-23.03585320491517,179.86237947171952] }, { 'startPoint' : [-5.570997193470086,172.0221729966046], 'endPoint' : [9.3243
34959688,9.376975066207507], 'startControlPoint': [10.884005326634842,164.63530320382674], 'endControlPoint' : [-4.968072864533834,110.626186
28577] }, { 'startPoint' : [9.324396434959688,9.376975066207507], 'endPoint' : [5.6297169670964,-110.17611809084356], 'startControlPoint': [2
53152351097606,-88.58724679549941], 'endControlPoint' : [-7.361202275296376,-53.760928830398264] }, { 'startPoint' : [5.6297169670964,-110.17
809084356], 'endPoint' : [53.717335525525975,-176.2424857013046], 'startControlPoint': [14.357981611994795,-148.08003333114038], 'endControlP
t' : [28.00328937556781,-176.2424857013046] } ]"
    |                  ^
  6 | }
```

why can't i use a comma in a string?

Comment: The `=` should be a `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close, but the pointer is actually pointing at the beginning of that line (though it is hard to see that).

```
default_bezier = "[ { \"startPoint\" : [51...
               ^
```

That `=` should be a `:`, like in the two lines above it.

Though it is hard to see, you can check it with the information the error gives you, specifically

```
expected token (5:16)
```

where `5` is the line number (in this case the line with `default_bezier = ...`), and the `16` being the column (character) number. If you count 17 characters from the beginning of that line (16 + 1 because 0 is the first column), you end up at the `=` :)